# How to print a specific instance of an object using toString

Tags: java, arrays, abstract-class, subclass, instanceof

How would I print and specific instance of an object using a toString?

So basically the user is inputing information. based on the input it will either saved in instance A or Instance B. Both instance A and B are subclasses with overriding toString methods. so the input from the user is saved in an array. How can I make it so that all the inputs that was an instance of A will print?

This is the code I currently have and it is not working.

```
public static void printA(ABC[] inputs)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++)
        {   
            if(inputs[i] instanceof A)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, inputs.toString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How exactly is it "*not working*"? Can you compile your code? Are you getting any results?

Comment: I can compile it I'm getting "LClient;@20d9896e" as the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need is

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, inputs[i].toString());
```

cuz you are trying to show the `array.toString()` not the value you want to.

Comment: this outputs everything in the array.. Is there a way to print out just the instance of A?

Comment: may be because ` if(inputs[i] instanceof A)` is true every time.

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating `inputs`, but testing `clients`. This is why I prefer to use a [`for-each` loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) and I suggest you use a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) to build a single message and then display it once. Something like,

```
public static void printA(ABC[] inputs) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (ABC input : inputs) {
        if (input instanceof A) {
            sb.append(input).append(System.lineSeparator());
        }
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sb.toString().trim());
}
```

**Edit**

The output you're getting ("LClient;@20d9896e") is because you are displaying `inputs.toString()`. Array doesn't override `toString()`, you can use [`Arrays.toString(Object[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28java.lang.Object[]%29) like

```
String msg = Arrays.toString(inputs);
```

But you'll get all of the items in the array. Also, make sure `Client` overrides `toString()`.

Comment: Is there any other way other than using StringBuilder? and what is sb.append?

Comment: It's [`StringBuilder.append(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append%28java.lang.String%29). And sure, you could use your `JOptionPane` but it will display a new message for every `A`.

Comment: is there anyway to print out all instances of A in the one JOptionPane?

Comment: @Mwam94 Yes. That's why I used a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: ok so adding Arrays.toString helps but as you said it prints out everything not the the instance of A. Overall what needs to happen is if the user wants to print out all of the instance of A they will select that from the menu and if they want to print instance of B they can do that.